# get result count for a search word

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, catalogsearch

I would like to find the result count for a certain search word before it gets automatically added to the search term list. I thought it would be simply `$query->getResultCount()` but this is returning NULL. I'm using `Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQuery()` to get the query before it gets saved in my `Mage_CatalogSearch_ResultController`.

Answer (score 1):

you can get it with `$query->num_results` if anyone needs this info in the future..